# how do i change my data field so there is no error in the relation?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a problem when I try to get data on the category table because there is a query error on the relation
error log:

```
SELECT `categories`.`id`, 
`categories`.`name`, 
`categories`.`color`, 
`transactions`.`id` AS `transactions.id`, 
`transactions`.`name_transaction` AS `transactions.name_transaction`,
`transactions`.`categoriesId` AS `transactions.categoriesId`, 
`transactions`.`amount` AS `transactions.amount` 
FROM `categories` AS `categories` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `transactions` AS `transactions` 
ON `categories`.`id` = `transactions`.`categoryId`;
```

**error :**

```
Error
    at Query.run (E:\project\budget_app\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:52:25)
    at E:\project\budget_app\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:311:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async MySQLQueryInterface.select (E:\project\budget_app\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:407:12)   
    at async Function.findAll (E:\project\budget_app\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1134:21)
    at async getAll (E:\project\budget_app\server\app\api\categories\controller.js:5:22)
```

**my table model :**
**- categories**

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class categories extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      categories.hasMany(models.transaction)
    }
  }
  categories.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    color: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'categories',
  });
  return categories;
};
```

**-transaction**

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class transaction extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      transaction.belongsTo(models.categories)
    }
  }
  transaction.init({
    name_transaction: DataTypes.STRING,
    categoriesId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    amount: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'transaction',
  });
  return transaction;
};
```

**my categories controller**

```
const { categories, transaction } = require('../../db/models');
module.exports = {
  getAll : async(req, res, next) => { 
    try {
      const result = await categories.findAll({
        attributes: ['id', 'name', 'color'],
        include:{
          model: transaction,
          attributes: ['id', 'name_transaction', 'categoriesId', 'amount']
        }
      })

      res.status(200).json({
        message:"Success",
        data: result,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  },
  }
```

how do i change so that it doesn't error

Comment: What does the error message say? Please add it to your question.

Comment: I don't have a categoryId field in the transaction table, but I have a categoriesId field, and the error is calling a categoryId field that I didn't define

ON `categories`.`id` = `transactions`.`categoryId`;
in this section I match the transaction.categoryId, it should be transaction.categoriesId

Comment: So, if you know, that it should be `transaction.categoriesId`, why don't you change it to that? Seems like an obvious error.

Comment: does that mean I repeat the model I made?

Comment: Can you not change it in the SQL query?

Comment: ok i tried it, thanks

Comment: So, it was just a typo in your SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your associations look exactly like you showed then you forgot to indicate `foreignKey` option with `categoriesId`:

```js
transaction.belongsTo(models.categories, { foreignKey: 'categoriesId' })
```

and

```js
categories.hasMany(models.transaction, { foreignKey: 'categoriesId' })
```